# getting error when Adding new Page content: floor_type in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to create a new floor type page "Interior Design"("3" in image) with content and category ( I have another 3 pages "Tile & Marble Floors"(2 in image) "Hardwood & Laminate" "Granite & Carpets" ). Other 3 pages working well. But When I want to create new display "3" in image. It conflicts with "Tile & Marble Floors" & "Hardwood & Laminate" pages. Most of the content comes from those 2 pages:: like 4 and 5 in the image.

Please see my image with the numbers.

[image]

```
1st :: I create a menu "Interior Design"
2nd:: I created category
3rd :: I created 5 contents (floor type) ::: content -> add new -> floor type
4th :: I go to the page structure->view->floor type content 
 then there is a page like screenshot I have provided.
 in display section :: there is button "+add"
5th :: I clicked +add button for "Interiror Design" (3 in image)
 like others ::: "Tile & Marble Floors"
```

BUT
problem is that "Interior Design" shows the content of "Tile & Marble Floors"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly this is the expected behavior. When you are creating a new display of an existing view, it will inherit all the configurations of the default display, i.e., the first display in your image.

If you want the new display to have different contents, edit each config, like title, fields etc.

When you edit, in a box at the top you get a drop down, which will say "**Apply to all displays**" by default. Go ahead and **change that to "Apply to this page/block"**. Then when you change, the new settings will be for that particular display, and not for the others.

Please let me know if you need more clarifications.

Comment: Perfect Dear. It fixed the issues. Thank you so much.  I Accept your answer. Thanks again.